# How to skip Devise authentication when using an API key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, authentication, devise

I'm using Devise on my application and would like to create a global API key that can access JSON data of anyone's account without having to log-in.

For example, say my API Key is `1234` and I have two users who have created two different restaurants.

- User 1 - Restaurant 1 (/restaurants/1)
- User 2 - Restaurant 2 (/restaurants/2)

And I open a brand new browser and haven't logged into anything and I pass into my URL `.../restaurants/2.json?api_key=1234`, I should be able to access the JSON data of that restaurant without having to log-in as *User 2*

Whats the best way to do this?

I've followed the [Railscast #352 Securing an API](http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api) so I'm able to access JSON stuff by passing in the API key but I have to log-in to see anything.

#### Edit 1: Using CanCan

I should mention that I'm also using CanCan for roles but not sure if that'll play any role (pun not intended) in this situation.

#### Edit 2: Implimenting with API Versioning

I followed the Railscast #350 and #352 which teach you how to create REST API Versioning and how to secure it with an API Key.

Here's what my controllers/api/v1/restaurants/restaurants_controller.rb looks like:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController
      before_filter :restrict_access

      respond_to :json

      def index
        respond_with Restaurant.all
      end

      def show
        respond_with Restaurant.find(params[:id])
      end

    private

      def restrict_access
        api_key = ApiKey.find_by_access_token(params[:api_key])
        head :unauthorized unless api_key        
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And my `application_controller.rb` still has the `before_filter :authenticate_user!` code in it.

## Solution

I first followed the [Railscast #350 on REST API Versioning](http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning) and moved all my JSON API calls to `/apps/api/v1/...`

Then, following Steve Jorgensen's solution below, made sure my API module inherited from `ActionController::Base` instead of `ApplicationController` so that it bypassed Devise's `before_filter :authenticate_user!` code within the `ApplicationController`.

So, my Edit 2 code when from looking like this:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController
    ...
```

to

```
module Api
  module V1
    #Replace 'ApplicationController' with 'ActionController::Base'
    class RestaurantsController < ActionController::Base
    ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option no one has mentioned is to have a completely separate set of controllers for the API that do not inherit from `ApplicationController`.

I have seen the pattern used where API controllers live in files such as `/app/controllers/api/v1/somethings.rb` and are accessible via routes such as `/api/v1/somethings`. Each of the specific API controllers inherits from a base API controller that inherits from `ActionController::Base`, so does not include any of the filters defined on `ApplicationController`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this a bit more please? I've followed Railscast #350 and #352 which teaches you how to create API Versioning and also secure it through an API Key. So how can I skip Devise authorization when an API Key is passed in? Right now, if you pass in a valid API key through .../api/v1/restaurants?api_key=1234 I still have to login.

Comment: You have `class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController`, so so your API controller inherits filters (and anything else) from `ApplicationController`. You need to bypass `ApplicationController` by inheriting directly from `ActionController::Base` instead -- or more likely, from an `ApiController` class that inherits from `ActionController::Base`.

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick! I'll update my question w/ the final solution.

Comment: I should note that although I got the check-mark here, others answers given here are also correct.

Comment: is this valid with current versions of devise also. becz its not working for me ?

Comment: I haven't kept up, so I don't know. It might or might not be valid with current versions of devise. I would hope that it is still valid though. What kind of "not working" are you experiencing?

Answer (score 18):

I know its been a while since this was asked, but thought I would throw in one more option that i've used in the past

```
class Api::ApplicationController < ApplicationController

skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

This assumes that you have an application controller in your API directory that all of your api controllers inherit from. If not, you can just put the skip in each controller.

Comment: `before_filter` is deprecated in Rails 5.0 and removed in Rails 5.1 https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.0.beta2/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb#L190-L193. Replace `skip_before_filter` with `skip_before_action` and `before_filter` with `before_action`, which are equivalent.

Answer (score 13):

You can do this with your `before_filter` in your Controller.

Currently, you probably have something like:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
end
```

Instead of calling this, you can define a different method (ideally in ApplicationController)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authenticate_or_token

  private
  def authenticate_or_token
    if params[:api_key] == 1234
      @current_user = User.new(:admin => true, :any => "other", :required => "fields")
      return current_user
    end
    authenticate_user!
  end
```

I would recommend using a more robust method of authentication such as OAuth, but this should work for a simple 1-key based authentication.

Comment: thanks for the response. However, I did what you said but I get a `NoMethodError in RestaurantsController#index. undefined method `has_role?' for nil:NilClass` when I try to access `/restaurants/2.json?api_key=1234`. My `ability.rb` file at line 28 is `if user.has_role? :admin  can :manage, :all  end`

Comment: what an elegant solution! just what I needed thanks a lot! @Gazler

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to Gazler's would be to use an except:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: :some_json_method

  def some_json_method
    render :nothing unless params[:api_key] == '1234'

    render :json
  end
end
```

This way you don't open your entire app to the key-holder (depending on your needs, whether you need that or not). 
If you need multiple methods opend to the key, you could probably also use something like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  JSON_METHODS = [method_1, method2]
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: JSON_METHODS
  before_filter :authenticate_token, only: JSON_METHODS

  private
  def authenticate_token
    params[:api_key] == '1234'
  end
end
```