# skipping devise authentication with rails new version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a rails 4 application. I am building api for it.

I have different namespace **api** for my api controllers. In my main app I am using devise as authentication. I want to skip this authentication for my api.

I tried some solutions on this answer
[How to skip Devise authentication when using an API key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784661/how-to-skip-devise-authentication-when-using-an-api-key)

***1st I tried***
I made new controller

```
module API
    class ApibaseController < ActionController::Base
    end
end
```

then I changed my topic controller to

```
    class TopicsController < ApibaseController
```

but its not working.

***2nd solution***

I tried

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

in my topics_controller

but still not working

I am using curl for testing 
I tried

```
curl -i -X POST -d 'topic[issue]=Zombie' http://localhost:3000/topics
```

Its giving error inn console

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found 
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Location: http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Request-Id: e1935321-d2b4-42c3-a452-f2eb3847b4c0
X-Runtime: 0.004413
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.5/2014-11-13)
Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2015 18:59:24 GMT
Content-Length: 101
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Please suggest solution for my problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide more details as to what isn't working? What specific error are you getting? Are you showing all your example code?

Comment: @jrhorn424 my TopicsController and ApibaseControoler is in same module

Comment: namespace :api do
      resources :users
      resources :topics
    end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75867/discussion-between-jrhorn424-and-adt).

Comment: Look into his http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445782/how-to-override-x-frame-options-for-a-controller-or-action-in-rails-4