# skip_before_action for a few controllers in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm building an api section for an app. My all api related controllers resides inside `app/controllers/api` directory.

My concern is that in `application_controller` there is a filter `before_action 
:authenticate_user!`, so I have to be in login mode to access the api.

**My current solution:** I'm adding  `skip_before_action :authenticate_user!` in all the controllers which are in 
`app/controllers/api` directory..

**Problem:** I have to write in all the controllers and I have around 80 controllers

**My expectation:** Is there a way where I can write in `application_controller` itself something like this
***before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [`all the controllers which are in api directory`]***

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11785449/2231236 implement similarly

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You will have to specify `skip_before_action :authenticate_user!` in every controller whose actions aren't supposed to be authenticated. You can not pass the name of controller or any thing like that as an argument to `skip_before_action` method.

One solution is: You can make a controller called `APIController`, and you can specify the `skip_before_action` thing there like:

```
class APIController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
  # rest of the code
end
```

And then all the controllers at `app/controllers/api/` can inherit from `APIController`.

```
class OtherController < APIController
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this if all the controllers are under API folder:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate!


  def authenticate!
    if params[:controller].split("/").first == "api"
      return true # or put code for what wherever authenticate you use for api  
    else
      authenticate_user!
    end
  end
end
```